# procedure to create dll using JRE 7 or JRE 8

Tags: java, com

Under windows XP / JDK 6, DLL creation from a jar file can be done with the packager, eg using .... \jdk\bin\packager.exe
Is there an equivalent procedure ? As i cannot find the "packager.exe" in jre7 or above..

Comment: That's news to me. Are you sure that isn't a command from somewhere else?

Comment: no the command looks like this...\jdk\bin\packager.exe myJar.jar myDll

Comment: and you're sure someone didn't copy it there from somewhere else in the last decade or so. Windows XP is ancient. How old is that JDK 6? What's the point of this conversion?

Comment: I want to register a java class file in windows system registry and use it for COM object.

Answer (score 1):

From [JDK packager tool](http://www.coderanch.com/t/512651/tools/JDK-packager-tool) :

"packager[.exe] appeared in 1.4.2 (I see it in 1.4.2_11, but not in 1.4.1_05 or 1.3.1_12), and then was renamed to pack200[.exe] in 1.5 and retains that name in 1.6"

However this information is not correct as `pack200.exe` is **not** a replacement for `packager.exe` (as the op correctly pointed out in his comment).

In the [ActiveX Bridge Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/beans/axbridge/developerguide/) there are the instructions for using `packager.exe` to generate a dll, for example:

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.2\bin\packager -clsid {D824B185-AE3C-11D6-ABF5-00B0D07B8581}
                           -out C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2\axbridge\bin
                           -reg C:\my_bean_jars\jelly.jar sunw.demo.jelly.JellyBean
```

From the [FAQ: JavaBeans Bridge for ActiveX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/faq-142262.html):

What is the status of Java Software's JavaBeans Bridge for ActiveX?

"The JavaBeans Bridge for ActiveX is currently part of the Java Plug-In. The ActiveX Bridge was **discontinued**with the J2SE 1.4.0 release."

From the [Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html):

"The Active-X Bridge has been **removed** from this release."

**Conclusion**

The functionality you are looking for was discontinued in 1.4 and the last pieces removed in 1.8.

Comment: pack200 is used to compress jar files...But i want to convert class file to dll file so that it can be registered in windows system registry and used as COM object.